# MySQL - Conditionnal printing results depending on binary criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting

i'm looking for a way to get my result in a certain way out of my sql query.

*Sorry for the bad title, if you have any suggestion to explain my problem better, tell me, and i'll change it*.
It's a bit difficult to explain with simples words so let me show you what i've and what i would like to get :

Here is the database i'm working on
It's filled up by a script, seeking on a printer server for any printing query

***DB structure***

[image: db structure]

***My query is here :***

```
SELECT SUM(pages*copies) as "nbpages", user, Grayscale
            FROM presentation
            WHERE Grayscale NOT LIKE ""
            GROUP BY user, Grayscale
            ORDER BY `user`  ASC, grayscale ASC;
```

The *WHERE* clause is only here to have two options : "GRAYSCALE" Or "NOT GRAYSCALE"

***Here are the result***

| nbpages | user | grayscale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 654 | user1 | GRAYSCALE |
| 5689 | user1 | NOT GRAYSCALE |
| 856 | user2 | GRAYSCALE |
| 45 | user3 | GRAYSCALE |
| 30 | user3 | NOT GRAYSCALE |

***And i'll like to get something like :***

| user | nbgray | nbnogray |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 654 | 5689 |
| user2 | 856 | 0 |
| user3 | 45 | 30 |

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple condition aggregation to me:

```
select
user,
sum (case when grayscale = 'GRAYSCALE' then pages*copies else 0 end) as nbgray,
sum(case when grayscale <> 'GRAYSCALE' then pages*copieselse 0 end) as nbnogray
from
<table>
group by
user
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, i didn't knew about the CASE clause in SELECT Statement.
Have nice day !

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT user,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Grayscale = 'GRAYSCALE'
                THEN pages*copies ELSE 0 END) AS nbgray,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Grayscale = 'NOT GRAYSCALE'
                THEN pages*copies ELSE 0 END) AS nbnogray
FROM presentation
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY user;
```

Comment: It worked, thanks lot, i didn't knew about CASE clause in select field.
Have nice day !